# Automation a Google Calendar from a Google Sheet using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api

So I have a central database of a load of events that I want to place into a Google Calendar. The issue is, sometimes the date is read correctly by the code and enters the event in the right place, and sometimes it cannot read the date even though it is in the same format and thus places the event in the calendar on 1/1/1970.

My sheet looks something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdMdD.png)

and my code is as follows

```
function addEventsToCalendar() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = 'c_';
  var eventsRange = sheet.getRange('A2:J' + sheet.getLastRow());
  var eventsData = eventsRange.getValues();
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

  for (var i = 0; i < eventsData.length; i++) {
    var eventName = eventsData[i][0];
    var startDate = eventsData[i][8];
    var endDate = eventsData[i][9];
    var category = eventsData[i][5];
    var recurrence = eventsData[i][6];
    var confirmation = eventsData[i][7];

    if (confirmation !== 'Added') {
      var startDateTime;
      var endDateTime;

      if (startDate && endDate) {
        if (eventsData[i][2]) {
          var startTime = eventsData[i][2];
          var startDateTimeString = startDate + ' ' + startTime;
          startDateTime = new Date(startDateTimeString);
        } else {
          startDateTime = new Date(startDate);
        }

        if (eventsData[i][3]) {
          var endTime = eventsData[i][3];
          var endDateTimeString = endDate + ' ' + endTime;
          endDateTime = new Date(endDateTimeString);
        } else {
          endDateTime = new Date(endDate);
          endDateTime.setDate(endDateTime.getDate() + 1); // Increment the end date by 1 day for all-day event
        }
      }

      var existingEvents = calendar.getEvents(startDateTime, endDateTime, { search: eventName });

      if (existingEvents.length === 0) {
        var event;

        if (recurrence === '') {
          event = calendar.createEvent(eventName, startDateTime, endDateTime, { description: category });
        } else {
          var eventSeries = calendar.createEventSeries(eventName, startDateTime, endDateTime, CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().interval(2));
          eventSeries.setDescription(category);

          event = eventSeries;
        }

        eventsRange.getCell(i + 2, 10).setValue('Added');
        Logger.log('Added event: ' + eventName + ' on ' + event.getStartTime().toDateString());
      } else {
        eventsRange.getCell(i + 2, 10).setValue('Skipped (Event exists)');
        Logger.log('Skipped event: ' + eventName + ' (Event exists)');
      }
    } else {
      eventsRange.getCell(i + 2, 10).setValue('Skipped (Already added)');
      Logger.log('Skipped event: ' + eventName + ' (Already added)');
    }
  }
}
```

I have about 70-80 events and sometimes it will run some of the events in the series (e.g there's 10 meetings with dates and times as in column I:J, sometimes it will add some of them and not the others even though they're all in the same format). Ideally I wouldn't want to have columns I and J at all but I don't think it is parsing the date correctly, or maybe I'm not parsing the date correctly. Apologies for what might be quite a easy to solve problem, I am only just learning the language.

Your help would be much appreciated...!

Comment: Try running Date() constructor of every read from the spreadsheet